# Will Ubuntu-SDK as module for other frameworks

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, qt-creator, clion

I use CLion. For me (and for most people, I suppose) QT Creator is not good choice for working. Will it be possible in the future to install Ubuntu-SDK to other programs (for example CLion)? Because CLion has become the best cross-platform program, and has better support.